# Resetting JSTL value

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I cant figure out why this is not working. Basicly the following code-snippet workes fine unless the `c:if` is true.

If the if-statement is true, then clientId should be set manually to 1. This does work, but for some reason then it will not fetch the clientProps.

ClientId=1 does work fine if it is fetched from the session-variable 'user'. So clientProps should have something at spot 1.
Any clue?

```
<c:set var="clientId" value="${sessionScope['user'].client.clientId}"/>
<c:if test="${empty sessionScope['user'].client.clientId}">
    True
    <c:set var="clientId" value="1" />
</c:if>

<c:set var="clientProperties" value="${clientProps[clientId]}"/>
<c:set var="clientLogo" value="${clientProperties.clientLogo}"/>
<c:set var="clientURL" value="${clientProperties.clientWebURL}" />
clientId = ${clientId}
clientLogo = ${clientLogo}
clientURL = ${clientURL}
```

Result if user-object exists:

`clientId = 1 clientLogo = /images/logos/Logo1.png clientURL = http://www.xxx.xxx`

Result if user-object doesn exist:

`True clientId = 1 clientLogo = clientURL =`

Comment: Are the types of `clientId` the same in both cases?

Comment: it is a Long when fetched from the 'User'-object. What it is when i manually set it i dunno..

Comment: Did you try setting it to a long? Don't know if it'll fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<c:set var="clientId" value="1" />
```

This is setting it as a `String` while the map key is apparently `Long`.

You need to set it as a `Long` instead.

```html
<c:set var="clientId" value="${1}" />
```

Numbers in EL are implicitly treated as `Long`, that's why the above will work.